# as3isolib : how to zoom with the same IsoView size?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, isometric

(development platform : Flex 4)

Context:

- Grid size : 64 x 64 cells
- View : 760 x 600 px

2 zoom levels are available:

- Min level : show all the grid (64 x 64 cells) in my IsoView
- Max level : only show 16 x 16 cells in my IsoView

How can I do that ?

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Just apply .zoom(factor) to your view.

For eg:

```
var view:IsoView = new IsoView();
view.zoom(3);
scene.render();
```

*Note: remember to click "accept" the answers if it answers your question.